# Add a listener in Objective C to activate keyboard input device

Tags: objective-c, macos, accessibility

I'd like to create a listener in my app that will be notified when the user sets focus to a text input element in any application (essentially to be notified when there is a blinking text cursor in the frontmost app). I am trying to use this to notify an external hardware device that the user wants to input text, and to switch to text input mode.

I've been through NSObserver, the shared workspace notificationCenter, etc, and not found anything like this. Is it possible?

I suppose I could try constantly polling the current focus object, but I'd rather have a listener.

Comment: So if the user is in any application whatsoever, as soon as they set focus on any input be it textField or textView, you want to send a notification to that external device?

Comment: Exactly. Messaging to the external device is all worked out, but figuring out when to activate the keyboard input mode is giving me trouble.

Comment: Not so sure if this is possible, you can send notifications to other apps, but those apps have to implement the required methods. You would need to make it so that every textfield that is accessed sends off a notification to the device, I just don't see how that would be possible without some sort of hack. You could try asking on Apple forums to see if something like this is even possible